# I am unable to install openpyxl in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, openpyxl

I am trying to install `openpyxl` for a beginner level excel spreadsheet exercise, but I am getting an error message: `Non Zero exit code(1)` stating that it is unable to install it. What is the solution for this? This is the image of my error message:

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

Does it give the same error when you run the `pip install openpyxl` on the command line?

Also try `pip3 install openpyxl` since you're installing the package to Python 3.7